# Getting elements of a 1 dimensional array Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, csv

How would I be able to print the last value of `element_val` numpy arrays. It is the second index of `[ 2.  2. 30.]` which is 30. So the values will go like `30,40,50...670,680`. How would I be able to do that since the numpy array is 1 dimensional?

input.csv file:

```
element,LNPT,SNPT,NLP,NSP,TNT,TPnL,MxPnL,MnPnL,MxU,MxD
[ 2.  2. 30.],0,0,4,4,8,-0.1,-0.0,-0.1,17127,-3
[ 2.  2. 40.],0,0,2,2,4,0.0,-0.0,-0.0,17141,-3
[ 2.  2. 50.],0,0,2,2,4,0.0,-0.0,-0.0,17139,-3
[ 2.  2. 60.],2,0,6,6,12,0.5,2.3,-1.9,17015,-3
[ 2.  2. 70.],1,0,4,4,8,0.3,0.3,-0.0,17011,-3
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_data = pd.read_csv('input.csv').to_numpy()
element_vals = my_data[:,0]
print(element_vals)
```

Output:

```
['[ 2.  2. 30.]' '[ 2.  2. 40.]' '[ 2.  2. 50.]' ... '[  6.    7.5 660. ]'
 '[  6.    7.5 670. ]' '[  6.    7.5 680. ]']
```

Comment: That output looks like you `print`ed an array to a file, rather than actually writing CSV, then tried to read the file as CSV anyway.

Comment: `print` should never be used as a way of saving NumPy array data. It discards data by default, and it's awkward to parse even when it doesn't discard data. Use `numpy.save` and `numpy.load`, or `numpy.savetxt` and `numpy.loadtxt`.

Comment: (Actually, considering details like the spacing and lack of extra brackets, it looks like you probably `print`ed a number of arrays individually, possibly `print`ing each row of a 2D array. Either way, it's a bad idea, and `pandas.read_csv` is the wrong tool to read this.)

Comment: Plus, `element_vals` has probably lost the first data row, since `read_csv` probably interpreted it as a column header.

Comment: If I read it directly from numpy it would give me an error and the `[ 2.  2. 30.]` values get outputted as `nan` when I use `genfromtxt` hence why I used pandas. I have updated to show what the issue to show what `input.csv` looks like.

Comment: Okay, so that is CSV. Embedding the string representation of a NumPy array in CSV isn't a great idea (for the same data loss and parsing issues mentioned before), but `read_csv` is an appropriate tool if you have to deal with this format, at least. You're going to have to parse those strings, since `read_csv` can't.

Comment: Is there any function I might be able to use that could parse it perhaps?

Comment: I'm guessing you started with a dataframe with array elements in one column, and did a dataframe `to_csv`.  When a column is object dtype, it writes the `str` version to the file; after all a `csv` is inherently 2d, so it can't write anything else.  `read_csv` has loaded those elements as strings.  `df` display doesn't show a difference, but the `to_numpy` does.

Comment: I think you have to parse it [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879345/parsing-the-string-representation-of-a-numpy-array).

Comment: There have been SO answers about parsing such strings.  You have to edit each string, either adding commas so it can be `eval` as a list, or stripped of [] it can be split.  There's no out-of-the-box fix that I know of.  If the original frame had list elements instead, the parsing would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`str.strip()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html), [**`str.split()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), and [**`to_numpy()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) to manually convert the `df.element` column into a real numpy array:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
element_vals = df.element.str.strip('[]').str.split(expand=True).astype(float).to_numpy()

# array([[ 2.,  2., 30.],
#        [ 2.,  2., 40.],
#        [ 2.,  2., 50.],
#        [ 2.,  2., 60.],
#        [ 2.,  2., 70.]])
```

Then you can index as expected:

```py
element_vals[:, 2]

# array([30., 40., 50., 60., 70.])
```