# Converting a string to an integer or float

Tags: python, list, floating-point, type-conversion, integer

I have the following list:

```
[[1.01782362e-05 1.93798303e-04 7.96163586e-05 5.08812627e-06
  1.39600188e-05 3.94912873e-04 2.33748418e-04 1.22856018e-05]]
```

When I return its type, I get:

```
<class 'str'>
```

Is the reason for that the scientific notation used for instance (i.e. e-04)?

In this case, how can I convert the above list to an integer or float?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The above list snippet comes from **[this CSV file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cin_PFWdMRpxv0D8QDvV-vYAeWe5Nf_6/view?usp=sharing)** under the "Feature" column.

Comment: What you posted is neither a string nor syntaxtically valid. Please provide a [mcve]. My guess is that the above is surrounded by quote marks that you did not include, but in that case there is no mystery as to why it is a string.

Comment: I would change your title to say "Converting scientific notation to a float".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Scientific Notation to Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099626/convert-scientific-notation-to-float)

Comment: I added the CSV file where the data is coming from to my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing the string-representation of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879345/parsing-the-string-representation-of-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1):

It looks a lot like you have NumPy's string representation of an array.  As I linked above, there doesn't seem to be a nice way of parsing this back, but in your case it might not matter, Pandas and Numpy can sort of get there reasonably easily:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# read in the data
df = pd.read_csv("features_thresholds.csv")

# use numpy to parse that column
df.Feature = df.Feature.apply(lambda x: np.fromstring(x[2:-2], sep=' '))
```

note that the `x[2:-2]` is trimming off the leading `[[` and trailing `]]`, otherwise it's mostly standard Pandas usage that most data science tutorials will go through.

Comment: if you can I'd suggest asking whoever gave you that file to give it to you in some other format that's easier to parse, e.g. a JSON dump of the array would likely be more portable than what you've got

Answer (score 0):

What you posted must be part of a string literal:

```
s = '[[1.01782362e-05 1.93798303e-04 7.96163586e-05 5.08812627e-06 1.39600188e-05 3.94912873e-04 2.33748418e-04 1.22856018e-05]]'
```

In which case

```
list(map(float, s.lstrip('[').rstrip(']').split()))
```

evaluates to

```
[1.01782362e-05, 0.000193798303, 7.96163586e-05, 5.08812627e-06, 1.39600188e-05, 0.000394912873, 0.000233748418, 1.22856018e-05]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use python ast (Abstract Syntax Tree) to process it efficiently

```
import ast
x = '[[1.01782362e-05 1.93798303e-04 7.96163586e-05 5.08812627e-06 1.39600188e-05 3.94912873e-04 2.33748418e-04 1.22856018e-05]]'
x = ast.literal_eval(x.replace(" ",","))
print(x)
```

Comment: Using `literal_eval` is a good idea.